# Inconsistency in ODE solution using solve_ivp when adding events

Tags: python, scipy, physics, ode, motion

I am using `scipy.solve_ivp` to solve an ODE in a loop, such that in every iteration I change some term in the ODE (which is like the force applied).

In terms of my problem - I just cant seem to understand why when I track events of zero crossing the solution sometimes stalls and essentially zeros out (as the figure below shows).
The code is a bit long, but only a small portion of it is actually relevant to my problem

(**1**) initialize some constants

```
MASS = 2.6e-4
WING_LENGTH = 0.07  # meters
GYRATION_RADIUS = 0.6 * WING_LENGTH
MoI = MASS * GYRATION_RADIUS ** 2 # Moment of Inertia
AIR_DENSITY = 1.2
WING_AREA = 0.5 * WING_LENGTH * (0.5 * WING_LENGTH) * np.pi  # 1/2 ellipse with minor radios ~ 1/2 major = length/2
# drag coefficients from whitney & wood (JFM 2010):
C_D_MAX = 3.4
C_D_0 = 0.4
C_L_MAX = 1.8
ZERO_CROSSING = 1
RADIAN45 = np.pi / 4
RADIAN135 = 3 * RADIAN45
```

(**2**) Define a wrapper which is a `RobotSimulation` class - it's an easy interface that allows to easily change the values of the ODE. The important function is `solve_dynamics` (the others are not part of the problem I believe)

```
def phi_dot_zero_crossing_event(t, y):
    """
    this event is given to solve_ivp to track if phi_dot == 0
    :param t: unused time variable
    :param y: a vector of [phi,phi_dot]
    :return:
    """
    return y[1]


class RobotSimulation:
    def __init__(self, motor_torque=lambda x: 0, alpha=RADIAN45, phi0=0.0, phi_dot0=0.01, start_t=0, end_t=0.05, delta_t=0.001):
        self.solution = 0
        self.motor_torque = motor_torque
        self.alpha = alpha  # angle of attack
        self.phi0 = phi0
        self.phi_dot0 = phi_dot0
        self.start_t = start_t
        self.end_t = end_t
        self.delta_t = delta_t

    def set_time(self, new_start, new_end) -> None:
        """
        we update the start time to be the end of the prev time and the end time
        as the last end time + the window size we wish
        """
        self.start_t = new_start
        self.end_t = new_end

    def set_init_cond(self, new_phi0, new_phi_dot0) -> None:
        """
        we update the initial conditions to be the last value of previous iterations
        """
        self.phi0 = new_phi0
        self.phi_dot0 = new_phi_dot0

    def set_motor_torque(self, new_motor_torque) -> None:
        """
        sets the moment to the new value
        """
        self.motor_torque = new_motor_torque

    def flip_alpha(self) -> None:
        """
        (Irrelevant for my question) changes the angle of attack's sign
        :return:
        """
        self.alpha = RADIAN135 if self.alpha == RADIAN45 else RADIAN45

    def c_drag(self) -> float:
        """
        calculates the drag coefficient based on the angle of attack
        """
        return (C_D_MAX + C_D_0) / 2 - (C_D_MAX - C_D_0) / 2 * np.cos(2 * self.alpha)

    def drag_torque(self, phi_dot):
        """
        the drag moment
        """
        return 0.5 * AIR_DENSITY * WING_AREA * self.c_drag() * GYRATION_RADIUS * phi_dot * np.abs(phi_dot)

    def phi_derivatives(self, t, y):
        """
        A function that defines the ODE that is to be solved: I * phi_ddot = tau_z - tau_drag.
        We think of y as a vector y = [phi,phi_dot]. the ode solves dy/dt = f(y,t)
        :return:
        """
        phi, phi_dot = y[0], y[1]
        dy_dt = [phi_dot, (self.motor_torque(t) - self.drag_torque(phi_dot)) / MoI]
        return dy_dt

    def solve_dynamics(self, phiarr, phidotarr, phiddotarr, angarr, torquearr):
        """
        solves the ODE
        :return:
        """
        phi_0, phi_dot_0 = self.phi0, self.phi_dot0
        start_t, end_t, delta_t = self.start_t, self.end_t, self.delta_t
        phi_dot_zero_crossing_event.terminal = True

        ang = []
        times_between_zero_cross = []
        sol_between_zero_cross = []
        while start_t < end_t:
            torquearr.append(self.motor_torque(start_t))
            sol = solve_ivp(self.phi_derivatives, t_span=(start_t, end_t), y0=[phi_0,phi_dot_0],events=phi_dot_zero_crossing_event)
            self.solution = sol.y
            ang.append(self.alpha * np.ones(len(sol.t)))  # set alpha for every t based on solution's size
            times_between_zero_cross.append(sol.t)
            sol_between_zero_cross.append(sol.y)
            if sol.status == ZERO_CROSSING:
                start_t = sol.t[-1] + delta_t
                phi_0, phi_dot_0 = sol.y[0][-1], sol.y[1][-1]  # last step is now initial value
                self.flip_alpha()
            else:  # no zero crossing
                break
        time = np.concatenate(times_between_zero_cross)
        phi, phi_dot = np.concatenate(sol_between_zero_cross, axis=1)
        ang = np.concatenate(ang)

        _, phi_ddot = self.phi_derivatives(time, [phi, phi_dot])
        phiarr.append(phi)
        phidotarr.append(phi_dot)
        phiddotarr.append(phi_ddot)
        angarr.append(ang)
```

(**3**) Finally the main function calls `solve_dynamics` sequentially for different values of actions and updates the time window and initial conditions:

```
phi_arr, phi_dot_arr, phi_ddot_arr, angarr, torquearr = [], [], [], [], []
phi0, phidot0 = 0, 0.01
start_t, end_t, delta_t = 0, 0.05, 0.001
sim = RobotSimulation()
for action in [1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1]:
    sim.set_motor_torque(lambda x: action)
    sim.solve_dynamics(phi_arr, phi_dot_arr, phi_ddot_arr, angarr, torquearr)
    phi0, phidot0 = sim.solution[0][-1], sim.solution[1][-1]
    start_t = end_t
    end_t += 0.05
    sim.set_init_cond(phi0, phidot0)
    sim.set_time(start_t, end_t)
phi_arr = np.concatenate(phi_arr)
phi_dot_arr = np.concatenate(phi_dot_arr)
phi_ddot_arr = np.concatenate(phi_ddot_arr)
angle_arr = np.concatenate(angarr)
```

Intuitively, as the actions I apply are just repeating `+1` and `-1`, I cannot understand why the blue points in the figure (see below) act so different

[image: plot]

Comment: Your time scale is incorrect. You should concatenate a time array from `sol.t` the same way you do for the solution components from `sol.y`.

Comment: To where exactly in the code is this refered? @LutzLehmann

Comment: Currently this only influences the production of the plots. Here the time scale should only go to 0.30, with the changes at multiples of 0.05. The points in sol.t are not equally spaced, they represent the sequence of actually used step sizes.

Comment: Oh, I see! this also explains the very triangular shape of phi - as I did use a plot with evenly spaced time

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, the problem was with how `solve_ivp` finds zero crossing points. It seems that the solution kept on finding the same <strike>crossings from `+` to `-`</strike> crossing every time  (Thanks Lutz), so I've added a restriction using the `.direction` variable:

1. before entering the `while` loop: `phi_dot_zero_crossing_event.direction = -np.sign(phi_dot_0)`. This makes sure we start by finding a crossing in the direction of the initial velocity.
2. when identifying an event in `if sol.status == 1`: I changed the sign of the direction with `phi_dot_zero_crossing_event.direction *= -1`

Comment: It is not so much that it only finds + to - crossings, it is that the same crossing is found repeatedly, as the numerical solver does not care to locate the root approximation for the event function after the crossing/event. Restarting the integration from a position before the event will find the same event again. /// Using qualitative properties like the crossing direction to enforce finding the real next root is the correct strategy.